# Office 2016/O365 default file locations in GPO

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I am currently in the process of rolling out 2016/365 and need to create a GPO so that the files are by default stored in the user's Documents folder.  I am not able to locate the place to configure for all of Office or does it need to be on a per application setting?  I am using %userprofile\Documents but want to make sure it is saving to the right location, I **CANNOT** have users saving to OneDrive as of yet.

Comment: There exists Office ADMX templates offered by Microsoft have you installed those?

Comment: I have installed the ADMX files and am not certain where to make the changes or change the settings.  I find information on Office 2013 but the settings are not the same, similar, but not the same.

Comment: What server version are you using?

Comment: @MichaelDeininger Why do you have the Office 2013 templates installed if your using Office 2016?

Answer (score 2):

make a GPO entry for : HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\General\PreferCloudSaveLocations DWORD 0 for NOT storing on OneDrive by default. That ought to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut
   to open the “Run” dialog box.
2. Type `GPedit.msc` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click “OK” to open Local Group Policy Editor.
3. Navigate to “Local Computer Policy” → “Computer Configuration” → “Administrative Templates” → “Windows Components” → “OneDrive”.
4. In the right pane, double click on the policy named “Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage”.
5. Select the “Enabled” radio button.

Use of OneDrive will be prohibited.

Comment: create gpo with this setting and apply to necessary groups/users